# What is nfc and its implementation

Tags: android, nfc

I don't know is this the right place to ask. Because I need to know the concept about NFC. From the Android 2.3 Platform reference. And i googled it. But i didn't get the correct concept. Can anyone please provide me good links and tutorials for that. And how to implement it in android.

Answer (score 6):

NFC = Near Field Communication

By using NFC tags you are able to scan these tags and retrieve information from the tag. This enables you to enhance physical objects with digital data. F.ex. posters can have a NFC tag and when you scan this tag with your NFC enabled mobile phone you can get some relevant information from the poster

There is a longer and better explanation on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication and there are also examples of use..

Additionally the Android SDK contains a NFC demo project.. take a look at it to see how it is implemented

Comment: Even the QR code gives us the information about the product. Then what is the difference between these two. I am asking this question because i am completly new to this concept.

Comment: The main difference is that with a QR code you will need a camera to scan the code. With NFC it is enough to just swipe your phone (or other device) across the NFC tag.

Comment: Another major advantage for the NFC tag is that it doesnt need to be visible for it to be scannable.. a QR code has to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine it as bluetooth with a very close field.

Answer (score 0):

NFC is a radio communications technology which works on an effective range of 4 cm. It is used to exchange small amounts or data (or settings up longer session) between devices in the implicit context of close proximity (and thus trusted parties). Passive tags can also be used.

After investigating NFC for about one month, my current impression is that NFC should be supported by most mobile applications, if only to share data with other devices. For example, a mobile web browser would share the link of the currently viewed page if an NFC session is initiated.

I have created an [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) if you would like to get started with some passive tags experimentation, it comes with a corresponding (free) Android app which does the actual NFC interfacing. I also recommend reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html) guide from Android.

Edit: Plugin now also supports some card readers :-)